# Pybluez Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pybluez

I was looking into source code for BLE scanner to understand it and customize it. I came across a function which I could not find any source code or documentation.

What is `HCI_FILTER_NEW()` function in Bluetooth library and how does it works? 
Also where can I find its source code?

Comment: This is a convenience wrapper from the python library. In the C layer it doesn't exist as you simply allocate memory for the structure and clear memory. Details [here](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/bluez/btmodule.c#L2522)

Comment: Thanks a lot.It was a great help